# php mysql query WHERE columnName equals a variable

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this php code:

```
$des = 'Caticlan, Aklan';

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM appDB WHERE route='".$des."%'";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));


$result = array();

//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
array_push($result,array(
        "id"=>$row['id'],
        "route"=>$row['route'],
        "busName"=>$row['busName'],
        "busType"=>$row['busType'],
        "assignedTerminal"=>$row['assignedTerminal'],
        "timeFirstTrip"=>$row['timeFirstTrip'],
        "timeLastTrip"=>$row['timeLastTrip'],
        "timeInterval"=>$row['timeInterval'],
        "estFare"=>$row['estFare'],
        "estDistance"=>$row['estDistance'],
        "estTravelTime"=>$row['estTravelTime'],
        "DualRoute"=>$row['DualRoute']

));  }

echo json_encode(array('busDetails'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

It should return data from db which matches `$des` in the query (and in `JSON` format). I tried to run this one but it only shows this result:

```
{"busDetails":[]}
```

But I expect it to return like this:

```
{
"busDetails": [{
    "id": "8",
    "route": "Caticlan, Aklan",
    "busName": "Ceres Liner",
    "busType": "regular",
    "assignedTerminal": "Molo Terminal",
    "timeFirstTrip": "03:30:00",
    "timeLastTrip": "20:15:00",
    "timeInterval": "20",
    "estFare": "0",
    "estDistance": "270",
    "estTravelTime": "4hrs 27min",
    "DualRoute": "San Jose, Pandan, Libetad"
}, {
    "id": "17",
    "route": "Caticlan, Aklan",
    "busName": "Ceres Liner",
    "busType": "regular",
    "assignedTerminal": "Ceres Terminal",
    "timeFirstTrip": "02:30:00",
    "timeLastTrip": "17:00:00",
    "timeInterval": "30",
    "estFare": "0",
    "estDistance": "226",
    "estTravelTime": "4hr 33min",
    "DualRoute": "Kalibo, Passi City"
}, {
    "id": "18",
    "route": "Caticlan, Aklan",
    "busName": "Ceres Liner",
    "busType": "aircon",
    "assignedTerminal": "Ceres Terminal",
    "timeFirstTrip": "03:00:00",
    "timeLastTrip": "17:00:00",
    "timeInterval": "30",
    "estFare": "370",
    "estDistance": "226",
    "estTravelTime": "4hr 33min",
    "DualRoute": "Kalibo, Passi City"
}]
}
```

There are no errors displayed. And I don't see any error in the syntax either.

Comment: Why do you expect to find any matches? Your query is looking for rows where `route` ends with `%`, but none of those routes have `%` in them. If that's supposed to be a wildcard, you need to use `LIKE`, not `=`.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM appDB WHERE route LIKE '".$des."%'";`

Comment: @Barmar Oh, my bad. I didn't see it. I was really confused as to what is wrong I didn't notice the `%` there. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @HailHydra Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't notice. My bad.